# How do I convert an XLS document to XML in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, excel, xls

I have an Excel spreadsheet that looks like:

[spreadsheet http://img186.imageshack.us/img186/6495/exelf.jpg](http://img186.imageshack.us/img186/6495/exelf.jpg)

I'd like to convert this to some XML that looks like:

```
<UserName>
bla1
</UserName>
<Mail>
bla1[at]bla2.com
</Mail>
<Address>
World
</Address>
```

can anyone help me do this in C#?

Comment: You may want to write a better title next time, I've gone ahead and fixed it up for you this time. Also, you'll get better results if you make an attempt on your own, and let us know where you got stuck. Plus, you may learn something.

Comment: I fixed the English too.  It is theoretically a good question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this Google result:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/b6e8a28c-6760-4e86-a1aa-e2ce9ec36380

Read the Excel file into a DataTable and use DataTable.WriteXml().

Comment: Not Work English your comment.

Answer (score 0):

try File | Save As, filetype .xml

Comment: This XML is probably too verbose, and probably considers the data to be rows/columns instead of usernames, email addresses, and addresses.  Might be a good first step, however; transforming XML trees is pretty easy.

Comment: @jrockway - the question has been tidied up now, it is now clear he wants a c# implementation, so my answer is irrelevant - but yes, i guess the native output would be verbose, and not configurable